# What's the correct classifier for `房子`?

Tags: mandarin, measure-word

In my little bit of Mandarin experience, I have got that the classifier for `房子` is `座`, and also felt that `座` is usually used to refer to a building. However, I have just read that [someone here over Chinese Language Stack Exchange](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/2306/grammar-for-counting-in-chinese-for-non-native-speakers-of-chinese) says the classifier is `栋`, and so I wonder which should be used to refer to `房子`.

Later I found that the classifier for `房子` may include more; in [this online dictionary](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?wdrst=0&wdqr=%E6%A3%9F%7C%E6%A0%8B%5Bdong4%5D), it shows `栋`, `座`, `套`, and `幢`. So I wonder how I can decide which to use and also like to know why.

Also, even if the proper classifier for `房子` is `栋`, could I still use `座` in that context? Or do they give two totally different meanings?

Comment: It's not really a matter of "correct classifier" as it is "when is which classifier appropriate?" Maybe see http://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1795/3561 for some help. I like thinking about it like water: a drop of water, a cup of water, a bottle of water: when do you use which?

Comment: isnt 所 also used? 一所房子

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All of them are OK to use to classify 房子, it depends on the type of house itself, which one is considered the more adequate.

- 幢 is preferred when speaking of large and tall buildings
- 栋 tends to be used to refer to buildings that are wide
- 座 is used for buildings that are “stable and steady", e.g. palace, temple, large mansions (mostly with public purpose)

Source: [Chinese University of Hong Kong](http://www.fed.cuhk.edu.hk/~pth/pth_passage01.php?passage=115)

As for 套 I have no reference, I suppose it has its own specific set of buildings it can classify.

Comment: And 一处房子, usually used together with a place indicator: 我在柏林有六处房子。

Comment: And 一间房子, usually used with small houses with a single room, but the meaning is broadened and you can see it being used with any kind of room: 我住在这间小房子十年了，现在我要买一间大房子。

Comment: 套 is referring to the logical aspect (a 'set' of rooms that function as one home) and is not necessarily a building, 一套房子 can be an apartment unit.

Comment: @NS.X. Correct, I would use 一套房间 in this case to refer to a suite of rooms/flat.

Comment: 套，is use to describe a set of  things,so 一套房，means it has bedroom,livingroom,kitchen....in short it emphasizes this house of  a suite of room.for example:我买了一套家具，It means i bought a  whole  set of furniture.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster 一套房间 sounds unnatural to me. It is common to say 我买了一套房子 (I bought a home), 他有三套房子 (he has three homes), etc.

Comment: @NS.X. Perhaps, but it is listed in (Chinese) online dictionaries http://www.ichacha.net/%E4%B8%80%E5%A5%97%E6%88%BF%E9%97%B4.html, as well as Pleco.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster Maybe a Southern/Northern thing but some of the examples in the link don't sound natural either. On the other hand, now I see where 一套房间 makes perfect sense - in contexts like booking hotel suites.

Answer (score 1):

in china,

房子's classifier depend on what it is using for,

like I want to describe my family rooms,i will use 一套房子

if I describe my room, use 一间房子

if I describe some buildings, always 一幢房子，一栋房子, these same meaning

Answer (score -1):

Only describe the number of property who owns can use 套：
Tom has 3套房子 in Beijing. He want to sell one of them for operation cost.