# Why number 2 has two forms?

Tags: grammar, etymology, number

二 (èr) and 两 (liăng)

[I understand when to use which](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/755/number-two-in-chinese-%E4%BA%8C-vs-%E4%B8%A4)

But I'm curious to know why, and correct me if I'm wrong, this is the **only number** that has 2 forms.

Comment: `二` usually used like English `second`.
`两` usually used like English `two`.

Comment: 1 also has two forms: 一 and 幺

Comment: You might even be able to say three has two forms 三 and 仨, but maybe just for some instances.

Comment: Isn't this found in most languages? You could even say that English "2" has *three forms*: **two**, **second**, and **pair**. Granted Chinese has three forms too (雙).

Comment: 仨 corresponds to 俩 for 2，thus might say 2 has 3 forms

Comment: are 20 and 30 not numbers too, note 廿 niàn and 二十 ，卅 sà and 三十

Comment: @user6065 its not common to use the ancient form.

Comment: bkrs：廿 twenty (20), in a limited number of set expressions also written using banker’s character
also note Japanese 二  On reading ni / に, i.e. of Chinese origin,   see Min Bei (KCR): nī etc. Korean in https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%8C#Glyph_origin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number two in chinese: 二 vs 两](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/755/number-two-in-chinese-%e4%ba%8c-vs-%e4%b8%a4)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A counterexample: in the Min Dong topolects, there is a similar distribution for the numeral "one", viz 一 and 蜀 (in Fuzhou, pronounced *ék* /ɛiʔ²⁴/ and *siŏh* /suoʔ⁵/ respectively). This is actually replicated across the other Min topolects (Min Nan has *it* vs *chi̍t*), although they are usually written with the same 一, especially in the Taiwan Ministry of Education standard for Taiwanese Hokkien. This comes from a well-known split between colloquial and literary pronunciations. For numbers above 10 however (11, 12, 21...) the literary pronunciations are generally used, even in counting before measure words.

Concentrating on the 二 vs 两 distinction: this seems to have emerged from Classical Chinese of the late Zhou, where it already had the meanings of "both/pair" (see the Analects), as well as starting to be a measure word for a chariot (see Mencius and the 詩經 Classic of Poetry). This is before most measure words have come into existence. Its use as a "tael" (measure of weight) is also ancient, but probably from a [different derivation of the word](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/16379/484) (Min topolects have a separate pronunciation for this word).

So where did these two very different "twos" come from? "Pair" as a separate word to "two" is well-attested in many languages. But language change can bring such words together and cause them to change role. Here, it was likely the [development of the measure word system](https://etd.ohiolink.edu/!etd.send_file?accession=osu1487856076411916&disposition=inline) through the Qin & Han dynasties to the Song dynasty, where numerical 二 came into a system (associated with nouns) that 两 (as pair) was already associating with. Hence in this case, 两 was already in the role and won out, whereas other numerals (including 12, 22 etc. with 二) took on the "measure word" role for the first time.